# how to use arrays before assigning values in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to fill an array using a loop in VB. It basically read a .txt file and store all the line in an array. Im getting this error. "Array is used before it has been assigned values".

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderDIR, "*.txt")
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileReader As StreamReader
Dim strReadFile As String
Dim arrLines() As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each fileName In fileEntries
    fileReader = File.OpenText(fileName)
    Do Until fileReader.Peek = -1
        strReadFile = fileReader.ReadLine()
        arrLines(i) = strReadFile
        i += 1
    Loop
Next
```

Is there any way I could do this, without pre-defining length of the array? I want the length of array to be number of lines in txt files. Hope i explained this well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderDIR, "*.txt")
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileReader As StreamReader
Dim strReadFile As String
Dim arrLines() As String = {} 'Added this
'Dim i As Integer = 0 'Removed this
For Each fileName In fileEntries
    fileReader = File.OpenText(fileName)
    Do Until fileReader.Peek = -1
        strReadFile = fileReader.ReadLine()
        If arrLines.Length = 0 Then ReDim arrLines(0 To 0) Else ReDim Preserve arrLines(0 To arrLines.Length)
        arrLines(arrLines.Length - 1) = strReadFile
        i += 1
    Loop
Next
```

Or so...

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a while, in vb6, I used **ReDim** to dynamically add a new entry in the array in the loop.
Inconvenient: slow down the process.
Better to count the occurrences needed from the file before creating the array.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Or, better yet, use one of the automatic collection classes. I can't remember if VB 6 had any of them (I think it did), but VB.NET certainly does. A *way* better option than `ReDim` if you don't know the size ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare arrlines as list:

```
Dim arrLines As New List(Of String)()
```

then you can convert to arrLines to array :

```
arrLines.ToArray()
```

try this:

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderDIR, "*.txt")
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileReader As StreamReader
Dim strReadFile As String
Dim arrLines As New List(Of String)()
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each fileName In fileEntries
    fileReader = File.OpenText(fileName)
    Do Until fileReader.Peek = -1
        strReadFile = fileReader.ReadLine()
        arrLines.Add(strReadFile)
    Loop
Next
arrLines.ToArray()
```

Comment: You do not need an array at all here. A List can do everything that an array can do. The `arrLines.ToArray()` conversion is pointless.

Comment: I agree. I just want to mention lists convert to array.